# Add HTTP GET method to C# web service

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, web-services, http-get

I want to access one of my web service methods via HTTP GET, I've seen it done before but I can't figure out how to allow this access protocol on a VS2008 web service project.

I guess you have to change the web.config file but not sure what to.

Does anyone know?

Comment: Are you talking about an ASP.NET web service or a WCF service?

Comment: I think the ASP.NET folks may have disowned their services. Microsoft now calls them "legacy". Better to say "ASMX Service".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your Web.config:

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <webServices>
            <protocols>
                <add name="HttpGet"/>
            </protocols>
        </webServices>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```